# RAID1 Drives Have Separated

Tags: bios, raid, raid-1

My wife came to me yesterday and asked me when I installed a new hard drive in our home office computer.  Since I hadn't installed any new drives I hopped on and saw that my 2-disk RAID1 drive had become two independent drives. I immediately backed up "both" drives to an external disk.

I checked Intel Rapid Storage and sure enough the volume has been lost.  However, I could not recreate it from within the utility as none of the involved drives would populate.

The issue is the same in the Intel BIOS utility (CTRL-i).  It reports a RAID volume is not present on the system but doesn't list the two 1TB drives that were being used to comprise the RAID1 previously.

So the drives are accessible to Windows but the system won't let me configure them as a RAID.

I believe I am the cause of this; I installed a new video card a couple of weeks ago and had to pull out a hard drive cage and reroute the SATA cables.  There are 4 drives in there, and I probably changed the ports the RAID drives were plugged into.  I haven't a clue which ports I had them plugged into originally.  I hadn't considered that this would be an issue.

Is there a way to recover the RAID1 at this point?  Or am I stuck resetting the CMOS/BIOS and starting over?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Your safest bet might be just recreating it and restoring from backup. And keeping backups up to date, of course (RAID is for availability, not backup).

Comment: I'm also assuming you haven't accidentally switched to AHCI mode...

Comment: Check your BIOS to see if somehow it switch from RAID mode to something else.